# Water Valve Orientation

Tags: plumbing, valve

I want to replace all the failing gate valves in my house with ball valves; and they are all installed on the vertical plumbing in between the joists, and these are rather inconveniently located. I would like to know if there's a reason that all of the valves are mounted vertically or if it would be ok if I replaced those gate valves with copper pipe and moved the new ball valves to the more-accessible, horizontal lines?

Comment: Valves usually don't care, they are on or off.  Place them where it is easy to use them and they do the job.

Comment: I would amend crip659 comment with ball valves usually do not have a flow direction but many valves do and they have a flow direction stamped or female threads on the inlet and male on the outlet.